# How to capture div content and display within a modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On the user clicking an image on the html page, the below uses jquery to capture that image and then display it within a modal pop up box.

I'd now also like to capture the contents of a div to pass to this modal box.

I've tried adding the below  `$(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');`, but this does'nt appear to work, what have I missed?

(I have added the .go class to the wrapper div)

```
               $( ".wrapper" ).on('click', 'wrapper');
               $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect_b');
```

---

Existing code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('.go').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
        $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
        $('#modal').reveal({
            animation: 'fade',
            animationspeed: 600,
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: can u create jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/m2AJs/1/ : WORKING FIDDLE FOR EXAMPLE**

---

To capture the content as you say you can use following methods :

**1.** `.text()` : http://api.jquery.com/text/

This will get you textual content of the div.

Use this if you need only text.

ex : `$("#modalDivId").text($("#divID").text());`

**2.** `.html()` : http://api.jquery.com/html/

This will get you the div as is, i.e. with any formatting, tags, or elements in it.

Use this if you need elements such as , ,  as well.

ex : `$("#modalDivId").html($("#divID").html());`

Answer (score 1):

Sample tutorial to capturing text from one div and show it another div [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gNJqu/)

```
<div id="Content">Hellooo World !</div>
<br/>
<br/>    
<br/>
<div id="modal"></div>
 <script>
 $('document').ready(function(){
 $('#Content').on('click',function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
 $('#modal').html(text)
 });
});
</script>
```